# What does the FFMpeg afreqshift filter do precisely?

Tags: ffmpeg

I was working to change the pitch of several audio files by a factor of 0.981818... and was trying to use FFMpeg, but now I have no idea what the afreqshift filter does or how it works. It seems to always reduce any frequency by a constant amount somehow, which basically makes music sound like that Mr. Incredible horrified meme music. I'm working on a potential different way to solve the pitch changing, but for now what IS this filter supposed to do, and how to properly use it?